# Пропускати чи уступати чергу

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Визначення взяті з СУМ-11

> ***[ПРОПУСКАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/propuskaty)*** аю, аєш, недок., ПРОПУСТИТИ, пущу, пустиш, док.,
> перех. і без додатка.
> **1.** Давати кому-небудь дорогу, прохід кудись, давати комусь, чомусь можливість обганяти, обходити себе.  //  Дозволяти кому-небудь пройти,
> проїхати кудись
>
> ***[УСТУПАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ustupaty)*** **1.** неперех. Те саме, що поступатися
> **2.** перех. Звільняти для іншого (місце, дорогу, прохід і т. ін.).
>
> ***[ПОСТУПАТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupatysja)*** **1.** перев. кому чим. Добровільно відмовлятися від
> чого-небудь на користь іншого або заради чогось; віддавати кому-небудь
> щось. *Поступатися (поступитися) місцем:* а) вставати або посуватися,
> звільняючи місце для кого-небудь.

Як правильно сформувати прохання пройти позачергово? ***Уступіть чергу/пропустіть позачергово/поступіться чергою?***

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю варто використати словосполучення "поступитися місцем у черзі". Згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupatysja) це дієслово підійде, адже там навіть вказаний варіант "Поступатися (поступитися) місцем". Також згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/chergha) можливі варіанти "поза чергою" та "позачергово", однак врахуйте, що коли ми кажемо "Він попав на прийом до лікаря позачергово", то маємо на увазі, що він потрапив туди не чекаючи у черзі.